# Need help For Invoice number generation

Tags: php

I have a table invoices with invoice_no column and I want to save a specific number with a following rules: `YEAR /month/day/(Invoice_number)` iteration from 1 to ... For next day, iteration go from start again.

For example:

```
Y-M-D1-(1)
Y-M-D1-(2)
Y-M-D1-(3)

#For next day
Y-M-D2-(1)
Y-M-D2-(2)
Y-M-D2-(3)
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: What is `D1`, `D2` etc? You want to count it from first day of business?

Comment: And your example does seem to match your rule.

Comment: Is there a database involved here somewhere? You've tagged the question PHP, but haven't shown any PHP code, or discussed where these invoice numbers are tracked. You might want to have a look at the articles in the [help] about how to help us help you by asking a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

You could count all the invoices that are created that day. You could do this with a simple query: `SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM invoices WHERE date(created_at) = curdate()`

That way you can generate an ID as following: `date(Ymd).$cnt+1)`.

Comment: What if you have entries of 1, 3 and 4  (say number 2 was deleted) - then the `COUNT()+1` will be 4.. But that already exists.

Comment: This would not be possible if it's always generated this way. If manual input is possible you could your option. Or save the count and get the highest number by doing ```SELECT max(invoice_count) FROM invoice WHERE date(created_at) = curdate()```.

Comment: Deleting a record has nothing to do with manual input - if you generate 1, 2, 3 and 4 (automatic increment, as the OP asked) - then for some reason, record 2 was invalid, and the user deletes it - you don't account for that, and that will cause problems if you generate more numbers that day.

Comment: Ofcourse, didn't think of deleting a record. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Select the highest (using `MAX()`) number - you can use `TRIM()` combined with `SUBSTR()` to filter out the other data - because you know that the date-format will always be 13 characters long (`2019-05-20-` has a length of 13). Then you're left with some number and a closing parenthesis, which you can `TRIM()` away.

Filter the dates by using `LIKE`, with a wildcard `%` at the end (meaning the string starts with the given value).

Given that it will return `NULL` when there are no entries by this date, use `COALESCE()` and give it a default value of 0 if no rows were found.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM SUBSTR(innvoice_no, 13))), 0) as HighestCount
FROM innvoice
WHERE innvoice_no LIKE CONCAT('2019-05-20', '%')
```

- Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3231e/13